# How to Check file type in openfiledialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open file and check the type of file.
I have a problem with Path.GetExtension. Is there other option to do this? 
I working in WPF. I tried with the following code

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog(); 
dlg.Filter = "Image (*.bmp, *.jpg, *.gif, *.png)|*.bmp; *.jpg; *.gif; *.png|All (*.*)|*.*";
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true) 
  string ext = Path.GetExtension(dlg.FileName); //problem
  if (ext == ".jpg")
    {...}
```

Error says:*'System.Windows.Shapes.Path' does not contain a definition for 'GetExtension'*

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? [`System.Windows.Shapes.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx) *really* does not have any member called `GetExtension`.

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with alias', you might need to explicitly state the namespace - I think its `System.IO.Path.Get.....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that WPF has a class called `System.Windows.Shapes.Path` (representing a drawing path), and you want `System.IO.Path` (for working with filesystem paths). Your file already has `using System.Windows.Shapes`. Adding `using System.IO` won't help because then the compiler won't know *which* `Path` you mean.

You can fix the problem by adding this line at the top of your file, which will tell the compiler that when you say `Path` you mean `System.IO.Path`.

```
using Path = System.IO.Path;
```

(Note: If you do this, you don't need `using System.IO` unless you're using other classes from `System.IO`.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dlg.FileName);` and it will work fine.